# C++ OpenGL rendering two rectangles with different colors

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shader

I have tried to create two rectangle objects with two different colors and moving in opposite direction. However, I am stuck in rendering the two rectangle with different colors (currently they are the same color).

What is the way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include "ogldev_util.h"
#include "ogldev_math_3d.h"

GLuint VBO1;
GLuint VBO2;
GLuint gScaleLocation1;
GLuint gScaleLocation2;

const char* pVSFileName = "shader.vs";
const char* pFSFileName = "shader.fs";


static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    static float Scale1 = 0.0f;

    Scale1 += 0.01f;

    glUniform1f(gScaleLocation1, sinf(Scale1));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    static float Scale2 = 0.0f;

    Scale2 -= 0.01f;

    glUniform1f(gScaleLocation2, sinf(Scale2));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
    glutIdleFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}

static void CreateVertexBuffer()
{
    Vector3f Vertices[6];
    Vertices[0] = Vector3f(1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[1] = Vector3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[2] = Vector3f(3.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    Vertices[3] = Vector3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[4] = Vector3f(3.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices[5] = Vector3f(3.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    Vector3f Vertices2[6];
    Vertices2[0] = Vector3f(-3.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices2[1] = Vector3f(-3.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices2[2] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    Vertices2[3] = Vector3f(-3.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices2[4] = Vector3f(-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    Vertices2[5] = Vector3f(-1.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices2), Vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

static void AddShader(GLuint ShaderProgram, const char* pShaderText, GLenum ShaderType)
{
    GLuint ShaderObj = glCreateShader(ShaderType);

    if (ShaderObj == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader type %d\n", ShaderType);
        exit(1);
    }

    const GLchar* p[1];
    p[0] = pShaderText;
    GLint Lengths[1];
    Lengths[0]= strlen(pShaderText);
    glShaderSource(ShaderObj, 1, p, Lengths);
    glCompileShader(ShaderObj);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(ShaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLchar InfoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderObj, 1024, NULL, InfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error compiling shader type %d: '%s'\n", ShaderType, InfoLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, ShaderObj);
}

static void CompileShaders()
{
    GLuint ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    if (ShaderProgram == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader program\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    string vs, fs;

    if (!ReadFile(pVSFileName, vs)) {
        exit(1);
    };

    if (!ReadFile(pFSFileName, fs)) {
        exit(1);
    };

    AddShader(ShaderProgram, vs.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(ShaderProgram, fs.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint Success = 0;
    GLchar ErrorLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Success);
    if (Success == 0) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error linking shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &Success);
    if (!Success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram, sizeof(ErrorLog), NULL, ErrorLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid shader program: '%s'\n", ErrorLog);
        exit(1);
    }

    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);

    gScaleLocation1 = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram, "gScale");
    assert(gScaleLocation1 != 0xFFFFFFFF);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 05");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    // Must be done after glut is initialized!
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
      return 1;
    }

    printf("GL version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CreateVertexBuffer();

    CompileShaders();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: We can't see your shaders, but I don't see you setting any color uniforms or vertex array bindings.  You need to either push the colors with the vertices as a different vertex array binding, as a uniform variable, or as a texture.

You also don't need to set your vertexattribpointer every time you render.  You should probably be using proper VAOs instead, so you can just swap your VAO binding to render multiple meshes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Easiest way in this case is to add `uniform vec3 color;` and `gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);` inside your fragment shader and then initialize it with desired color by invoking `glUniform3f` before rendering of each rectangle. However, with rectangle count growth you would be better to create your vertex `struct` that will carry not only coordinates, but a color as well.
Also, I highly recommend this http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ opengl tutorials web site.

Comment: I have added color in the fragment shader but how do i invoking it to be one green and one red? what is the right way to use glUniform3f?

Comment: You need to invoke it anywhere between `glUseProgram` and `glDrawArrays`. First argument is a uniform location, next 3 - each component of vector (In this case, color - rgb. They should be between 0.0 and 1.0): `glUniform3f(colorUniformLocation, r, g, b);`. In your case it's: `glUniform3f(colorUniformLocation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` after `glUniform1f(gScaleLocation1, sinf(Scale1));` and `glUniform3f(colorUniformLocation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);` after `glUniform1f(gScaleLocation1, sinf(Scale2));`.